# Scraping HS Football Data Yielding Empty XML

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am a NJ HS football coach who is trying to scrape standing features to forecast playoff standings. This is the web page I am attempting to pull: https://www.gridironnewjersey.com/schoolDetail.aspx?schoolId=2

For some reason, when I read the HTML, I am getting a lot of blank XML or character nodes. It is important that I am able to retrieve, for example, the strength index on this page, but I can't get it to come up. It would also be helpful to retrieve the Power Points from here: https://www.gridironnewjersey.com/schoolDetailPP.aspx?schoolId=2

Again, I am not able to get the full table.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: What code have you tried running? Please show what you have tried so we can also test it and provide alternatives. What exactly is the required output?

Comment: test_html <- read_html("https://www.gridironnewjersey.com/schoolDetail.aspx?schoolId=2")

then i used a selector gadget to try and find the nodes that i wanted: test_node <- html_nodes(test_html,"dl")

Ideally I would like to get the Team Name and Strength number from the first page, and then pull the entire table from the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```r
library(rvest)
html <- read_html("https://www.gridironnewjersey.com/schoolDetail.aspx?schoolId=2")

# team:
html_element(html, "h1") %>% html_text()
#> [1] "Allentown Redbirds"

# Strength Index (xpath instead of css selector: 1st dd element following a dt element with sepcific text)
html_elements(html, xpath = '//dt[text()="Strength Index:"]/following-sibling::dd[1]') %>% html_text()
#> [1] "70.43"

# table (without selecting a table element first, html_table would return a list tables)
read_html("https://www.gridironnewjersey.com/schoolDetailPP.aspx?schoolId=2") %>% 
  html_element("table") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#>    Date  Opponent       `Opponent Record` `Opponent Group` Result `Power Points`
#>    <chr> <chr>          <chr>                        <int> <chr>           <int>
#>  1 08/25 Brick Memorial 9-0-0                            4 L                   7
#>  2 09/01 Notre Dame     9-0-0                            2 L                   7
#>  3 09/09 Steinert       3-4-0                            4 W                  19
#>  4 09/14 Robbinsville   5-4-0                            3 W                  18
#>  5 09/22 Bordentown     3-5-0                            2 W                  14
#>  6 09/29 Lawrence       0-9-0                            3 W                   9
#>  7 10/06 West Windsor-… 5-2-0                            5 W                  26
#>  8 10/06 West Windsor-… 6-3-0                            5 W                  26
#>  9 10/12 New Egypt      3-6-0                            1 W                  16
#> 10 10/20 Hightstown     3-6-0                            4 W                  19
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Use of `html_nodes()` hints that you might be following some rather old guide or resource, so perhaps check https://r4ds.hadley.nz/webscraping